# How to sort data in store depending on conditions in senchatouch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I insert data in store depending on conditions

```
Ext.getStore('storename').add({
PlanUnplanned:data[i].PlanUnplanned==null?"Unplanned":Planned,
});
```

Now I am using dataview / dataitem to display the records. How do I sort the store such that the planned records are displayed first and the unplanned records are displayed next in sequence

Answer (score 0):

You can change your store sorting like this:

```
Ext.getStore('storename').sort('PlanUnplanned', 'ASC');
```

You also can define that direct on your store

Source: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store